# Comparing column to another

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

```
deliverable_id deliverable_title deliverable_desc adviser_id passed_user deliverable_passed flag
             1 SRS               kogtong                   1           0                  0    0
             2 WEBSITE           Lorem ipsum...            1           0                  0    0
             3 system            asdsadasdasdasd           1           0                  0    0
             4 software          sdgdThyiliul234           1           0                  0    0
             5 NULL              NULL                      1           4                  1    1
             6 NULL              NULL                      1           4                  2    1
```

I want to make a query that would compare if `deliverable_passed` is the same as `deliverable_id`. If they are the same, it would not print the the same `deliverable_id`.

This is my current query is :

```
SELECT * FROM deliverable
WHERE deliverable_id!=deliverable_passed
```

The current output is (based on `deliverable_id`) : 1 2 3 4

My expected output after comparing would be (based on `deliverable_id` ) : 3 4

Since `deliverable_passed` values 1 & 2 already exist.

Comment: Why wouldn't you get 5 and 6?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 5 and 6 would be my record that a user has submitted a deliverable. the 1 2 3 4 is a constant record. therefore if 5 and 6 has passed 1 2 it would only display 3 and 4

Comment: You seem to have a rather bad database design.  You are using the same table to store what the deliverables are as well as who has submitted what deliverables.  You should separate this into two tables - one for deliverables and one for submissions - this way you'll find it much easier to query for information.

Comment: Seems like i have a bad database design. im changing my database splitting the table deliverable and adding a new table passed_deliverable splitting the last 3 column in the table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select all deliverables (that have a title) where no record *exists* with their deliverable_passed ID. So use NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT * 
FROM deliverable
WHERE deliverable_title is not null
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT * FROM deliverable passed
  WHERE passed.deliverable_passed = deliverable.deliverable_id 
);
```

Or even simpler with NOT IN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM deliverable
WHERE deliverable_title is not null
AND deliverable_id NOT IN (SELECT deliverable_passed FROM deliverable);
```

(But Aleks G is right. This is a horrible database design and you should change it.)

Comment: I agree, this is my bad. an un efficient database design. currently changing my database design. but thanks for the answer this code worked

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select d.*
from deliverable d
where exists (select 1 from deliverable d2 where d2.id = d.deliverable_passed) or
      exists (select 1 from deliverable d2 where d2.deliverable_passed = d.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **SELF JOIN** to check for passed deliverables.

Try this:

```
SELECT d1.* 
FROM deliverable d1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN deliverable d2 ON d2.deliverable_id = d1.deliverable_passed
WHERE d2.deliverable_id IS NULL
```